# Pyodbc fails to connect with driver error for mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymongo, pyodbc

I am using the pyodbc to connect with my local database with python2.7.

The code I use:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    "Server=localhost;"
    "Database=Employee;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Error I got:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: Are you using `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` to connect to `mysql`?

Comment: yeah, is that a problem?@HoneyBadger

Comment: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused (Connection refused). Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.". I received this while connecting with sql.

Comment: You see, the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server tries to connect to a SQL Server database. To connect to a MySQL database, you need a MySQL ODBC driver.

Comment: I have installed it@jarlh